# Is "thought'd" Proper English?

Tags: contractions

Instead of "I thought I would" or "I thought I'd", I sometimes write "I thought'd". I don't know if this is correct English, however. I mean, you can say "We'd", right? So, why not "thought'd"?

Comment: I'm voting to close as "too localised". As @Barrie says, in sloppy/rapid speech, *thought I would* might just about be heard as *thought'd*, but I'm sure hardly anyone would be minded to *write* it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*We’d* is a contraction of *we would*. *Thought’d* is not analogous. In rapid speech *I thought I'd* may come out as something like that, but there is no conventional way of representing it writing.

Answer (score 2):

Thought'd would be a contraction of "thought would," and so in your example would not be proper English. It is a grayer area for such an example as contracting "my thought would be" to "my thought'd be."

Answer (score 2):

English has many, many spoken weak [clitics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic) that have no corresponding written forms. Some of them are only found in regional dialects. Some people say "Ahmina go to the store", short for "I am going to go to the store".

Some of these have written forms, like "we'd", "wouldn't" and "could've". Some of them are written only very informally, like "gonna" (for "going to"). But this one has no corresponding written form. The pronunciation may be perfectly acceptable in some regions, but it has no written form.

Comment: Poor Ahmina, always being ordered around.